# remote desktop licensing error with windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

we have windows server 2008 R2 installed on our server. we use remote desktop to access it via LAN from 8 -10 client machines (6 different users). While this setup was working correctly for the past year.The following error occurs on **SOME** of the client machines 
"Disconnected due to an error in licensing protocol"
Can I know how to fix this? if there is a problem with licensing why does it occur only on some client machines? (all clients use windows 7)
Thanks.

Never mind. I was able to do it with the following steps:
First delete the registry folder MSLicensing from the client machine.
Next, Run Remote desktop in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was able to do it with the following steps:

- First delete the registry folder `MSLicensing` from the client machine
- Next, Run Remote desktop in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

This problem made by some kind of caching of remote desktop licensing in clients you can solve this by remove the bellow key in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing
```

It's much convenient to make a reg file and run it so .

1. Make a empty text file
2. Name it "mypatch.reg" or "mypatch.reg"
3. Put bellow text in it and save it

   ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing]
   ```
4. Run it by dubble click on file!

It should remove the key.